# Which interval do we use at the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)>1$ for each $x>0$.

I want to show that there is $\xi >2$ such that $\frac{f}{x}>\frac{1}{2}$ for each $x>\xi$.

$$$$

For that do we have to use the mean value theorem?

But for which interval? I got confused with the $2$ at $\xi>2$.Do we have to consider for each $x>2$ the intervals $[2,x]$ to apply that theorem?

Is yes, then we have that there exists $\xi\in (2,x)$ such that $$\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=f'(\xi)>1$$

How do we continue from here?

Or do we consider the intervals $[2,x]$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, prove that $f(x) > x+f(0)$ for $x>0$, using the MVT. From there you easily get to $f(x)> \frac 12x$ for $x>-2f(0)$.

Comment: Ok! I proved the first part. For the second part do we apply again the MVT? Or do we just use an inequality for $f(0)$ ?

Comment: Keyword: transitivity of relations

Comment: But can we just say that $x>-2f(0)$ ? And at the statement we have that $\xi>2$, how do we get this $2$ ?

Comment: Dude, when it holds for $x>-2f(0)$, then it holds for $x > 10000000$ (or larger) and $1000000 > 2$.

Comment: Ok! We get the desired inequalitywhich holds for every $x>-2f(0)$ and so it holds alsofor every $x>\xi$ where $\xi>2$, is that correct?

Comment: Not for arbitrary $\xi>2$ of course. But there exists such a $\xi>2$. The number $2$ is really not important here. Take $f(x) = 2x-1000000000$ for example. You always have $f'(x) = 2>1$ but $f(x)/x > 1/2$ only holds for very large $x$.

Comment: @MaryStar Let $\xi=\max\{3,-2f(0)\}$. Then $\xi>2$ and for all $x>\xi$, $f(x)>x+f(0)>\frac12x$

Comment: Aaa!! I got it!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @MaryStar Not a problem. Please check my answer.

Comment: Ok! I will do that! One question... To check the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=[\xi]+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{f(n)}$$ we have to use the above inequality, i.e. for $n>\xi$ it holds that $f(n)>\frac{n}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{f(n)}<\frac{2}{n}$ and so $\frac{(-1)^n}{f(n)}<\frac{2(-1)^n}{n}$. We can show that $$\sum_{n=[\xi]+1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^n}{n}$$ converges and so the original series converges also. Is that correct?

Comment: @MaryStar No, this is not correct. Note that $0 < a < b$ implies $-b<-a$. What you need here is that $f(n+1)\ge f(n)$ (in order to apply Leibnitz criterion), which is of course true as $f'>0$.

Comment: I got stuck right  now. Which part of my comment is not correct?

Comment: @MaryStar You claimed that $\frac{(-1)^n}{f(n)} < \frac{2(-1)^n}{n}$. Now, choose a negative $n$. Then this means $-\frac{1}{f(n)} < -\frac{2}{n}$ and thus $\frac{1}{f(n)} > \frac{2}{n}$ or, equivalently, $f(n) < \frac n2$. Do you see now?

Comment: But at the series the lower bound is $[\xi]+1$, so $n\geq [\xi]+1$ and we have that $\xi>2$, so $n$ cannot be negative, can it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean negative but odd, so $(-1)^n$ becomes negative.

Comment: Ah ok... I see! So we use here the Leibnitz criterion since we have an alternating series, correct? I have also to check two other series using the above function. Can you tell me if I use the correct criterion?

Comment: $$ (1)  \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n[\xi]+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(n)\log^2(n+1)} \\ (2) \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(f(x))^n} \ \ \text{ with } x>\xi$$ At (1) I used again the inequality $f(n)>\frac{n}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{2}{n+1}>\frac{1}{f(n)}$ and so $\frac{1}{f(n)\log^2(n+1)}<\frac{1}{(n+1)\log^2(n+1)}$. Using integral criterion we see that the series of the right side converges and so also the left one.

Comment: At (2) we have for $x>\xi$ that $f(x)>\frac{x}{2}$ and so $$\frac{n^2}{(f(x))^n}<n^2\cdot \left (\frac{2}{x}\right )^n$$ Using the ratio test for the series of $n^2\cdot \left (\frac{2}{x}\right )^n$ using the fact that $\frac{2}{x}<1$ since $x>\xi>2$ we see that the series of the right side converges and so also the left one. Is everythig correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, this is all correct. Very good! You get an A. ;-)

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: Not a prob.....